# PHP XMLReader start reading from a certain node element number

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

Not sure if this is possible, for example if I have an XML file that have millions of "item" elements, can I skip the 1 - 100 "item" elements and start reading from the "item" element number 101?

XML example:

```
<items>
   <item>
      <name>ABC</name>
      <price currency='USD'>100</price>
   </item>
   <item>
      <name>DEF</name>
      <price currency='USD'>120</price>
   </item>
   <!-- .... and a lot more item elements -->
</items>
```

Here is my current code:

```
$z = new XMLReader;
$z->open('1.xml');
$doc = new DOMDocument;
while ($z->read() && $z->name !== 'item');
$i = 1;
while ($z->name === 'item'){
   if($i<=100){
      $z->next('item');
   }else{
      $node = new SimpleXMLElement($z->readOuterXML());
      //doing my stuff here, extracting the node information of that <item>
      $z->next('item');
   }
   $i++;
}
```

as you can see from above, I just use "next" to skip item number 1-100, but this is not very efficient.
Appreciated if you guys can help on this. Thanks!!

tried solution from @DHRUV GUPTA:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file('1.xml',"SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_PARSEHUGE);
$xml = json_encode($xml);
$xml = json_decode($xml,true);
for($i=99; $i<=104; $i++){
   echo $xml["item"][$i]["name"]."<br />";
}
```

but got "parser error : out of memory error" error.

Comment: Instead of skip 1 to 100 try to read xml using node.

Comment: @Hkachhia can you explain more?

Comment: Problem is that unless you actually read the data, you can't tell what size each element it is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible, you need to loop through items and start from 99th item. For example:-

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($myXMLData) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$xml = json_encode($xml); // encoding in json format
$xml = json_decode($xml,true); // again decode with second parameter true to get object as array
for($i=99; $i<count($xml['items']); $i++){
  // here you can use $xml['items'][$i] which will be 100th element
}
```

For large file you need to use LIBXML_PARSEHUGE flag in simplexml_load_string function.

```
simplexml_load_string($xml, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_PARSEHUGE)
```

XML_PARSE_HUGE flag relaxes any hardcoded limit from the parser. This affects limits like maximum depth of a document or the entity recursion, as well as limits of the size of text nodes.

Increase php memory limit in case of large file

```
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');
```

Comment: Hi @DHRUV GUPTA thanks for your answer
but for this case I cannot use simplexml_load_string because the XML file is very huge 2GB++ and using simplexml_load_string will take a long time to load.

Comment: @JohnFive For large file you need to use LIBXML_PARSEHUGE flag in simplexml_load_string function. Please check updated answer for explanation.

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't work, it show "parser error : out of memory error", detail added in my first post

Comment: @JohnFive try increasing you php memory limit using init_set. check my updated answer.

Comment: added ini_set('memory_limit','1024M'); at the top of the script, it takes too much time to finish loading and end up with out of memory again, I guess this is not workable, I still think using XMLReader is better.
Anyways thanks for your help!

Comment: @JohnFive yes it will take time but you can fetch it once and store it in session or cookie and then read from there. also if it still gives error increase memory from 1024 to 4096M.